# Not able to send passwordHash to MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

I am using the following code

```
$q = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, email, passwordHash) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

$q->bind_param('ssss', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $passwordHash);

$firstName = trim($_POST['firstName']); 
$lastName = trim($_POST['lastName']); 
$email = trim($_POST['email']); 
//$passwordHash = '$2y$10$Q0Z2OTSOjLqXA3XWscvDxO70GfY0LdQrJ/oUfxty4APU763D0iuJW'; 
$passwordHash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
echo $passwordHash;
$q->execute();
$q->close();
```

When I use the commented out line the statement executes and the table is updated. When I use the passwordHash that isn't commented out the database isn't updated. Is there something extra I need to do to make the hash suitable for the INSERT? From the PHP docs the return from password_hash() is a string.

Comment: do you have a value coming in $_POST['password'] ?

Comment: Yes, the hard-coded string I am using that does work is from the echo of $passwordHash

Comment: you placed the wagon before the horse here (for all of them). I'm voting this as a typo.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner can you explain what you mean?

Comment: meaning, that you defined them "after" the first 2 lines.

Comment: it works if I don't try and add the passwordHash and if I have the definition before the bind statement then it doesn't work at all. In the docs it is also defined after. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: what's the version of php this is running on? make sure that hashing function is available to your server.

Comment: it was running on 5.4, just updated it to use 5.5 will see if this helps. I think the hashing should be working as it does echo a hash?

Comment: I posted an answer below since this went further than originally known and retracted my vote to close.

Comment: Also, if you upgraded on your own local machine, make sure you restarted everything after making that upgrade from 5.4 to 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, and as I stated in comments, you should define your variables "first", then prepare/execute. What you're doing now could have adverse effects, so it's just "good practice".

```
$firstName = trim($_POST['firstName']); 
$lastName = trim($_POST['lastName']); 
$email = trim($_POST['email']); 
//$passwordHash = '$2y$10$Q0Z2OTSOjLqXA3XWscvDxO70GfY0LdQrJ/oUfxty4APU763D0iuJW'; 
$passwordHash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
echo $passwordHash;

$q = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, email, passwordHash) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

$q->bind_param('ssss', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $passwordHash);


if($q->execute()){
   echo "Success!";
} else {
   echo "Error: ". mysqli_error($connection);
}
$q->close();
```

**Note:** If [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is not available on your server due to a version that does not support it, you will need to use the password compatibility pack for it, as shown in the manual for it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)

User contributed note:

> There is a compatibility pack available for PHP versions 5.3.7 and later, so you don't have to wait on version 5.5 for using this function. It comes in form of a single php file:
>   https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

As I am typing this, I noticed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356640/not-able-to-send-passwordhash-to-mysql-table-with-php/52356789#comment91658075_52356640) from you:

> it was running on 5.4, just updated it to use 5.5 will see if this helps. I think the hashing should be working as it does echo a hash?

**That is entirely it.** - `password_hash()` isn't available to use on PHP 5.4. See above about the password compatibility pack.

Also make sure that the password column's length is long enough to hold the hash. The manual suggests 255. If it's less than 60, there's a problem; it's too short.

Use error handling: (which I included in a slight edit to your execute).

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (would have thrown you an error about that function not available).
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thank you. This is working now. I am also glad that you can define the variables first as this is what I had done and I was then having to bring them down to use in this statement. Many thanks for also pointing out the PHP version.

Comment: You're most welcome @a.norman glad to have seen/known the version of php it was originally working off from, *cheers* :-)